# How to activate (N)RVO for aggregates in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, return-value-optimization

Is it true that Visual C++ supports (named) return value optimization (N)RVO for aggregates?

In the example as follows:

```
struct Vector
{
    float data[100];
};

void print(const Vector & v);

inline Vector makeVector()
{
    Vector c;
    return c;
}

void foo()
{
    print(makeVector());
}
```

compiled with optimization (/O2 switch)
https://godbolt.org/g/bb8HZj
one can easily see that there is copying of the Vector constructed in makeVector() function

```
    lea      rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx+128]
    movups   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
    lea      rax, QWORD PTR [rax+128]
    movups   XMMWORD PTR [rcx-128], xmm0
    movups   xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax-112]
    movups   XMMWORD PTR [rcx-112], xmm1
    movups   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax-96]
    movups   XMMWORD PTR [rcx-96], xmm0
    ...
```

So it is clear that there is no NRVO here as in other compilers. Is there a way to turn on or activate it in Visual C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MSVC does not apply RVO to types that are seen as C structures. The solution is to make your `Vector` look like a C++ type (make it non-POD, but I am not sure if POD is what MSVC uses here). Try this:

```
struct Vector
{
    Vector() { }

    float data[100];
};
```

Careful, as it changes semantics: you won't be able to zero-initialize it with `Vector v{}`.

Comment: You basically suggest making `Vector` not-aggregate. And you properly say that your version will not default-initialize `data` with zeros. To make both `Vector` not-aggregate and keep its default initialization, the constructor has to be defined as follows: `Vector() : data{} {}`. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xc5b9G8M3